# Katalon browser authentication on Mac

Tags: macos, authentication, katalon-studio

Im trying to automate a site (using Katalon) that uses browser authentication on a Mac.

I can see that Windows users can use the [Authenticate](https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/%5BWebUI%5D+Authenticate) keyword, but is there a similar keyword or setting / configuration option for Mac users?

Answer (score 0):

A way i was able to solve this was by adding credentials via the url as seen in [Can you pass user/pass for HTTP Basic Authentication in URL parameters?](https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters)

Changing the url to the following format solved the problem:

```
WebUI.navigateToUrl('https://username:password@example.com/')
```